# css3 button cursor: pointer is not working

Tags: html, css, pointers, button, cursor

```
button {
    margin: 10px;
   padding: 5px;
   background-color: lightsalmon;
   width: 20%;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: white;
   border: 1px double dodgerblue;
   border-radius: 3px;
   cursor: pointer;
  }
```

the above is my css  code

and the below is my html code

`<button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button><br><br>`

when I hover the cursor over the button the cursor is not turning into pointer ,can you tell is there any mistake in the code I have given

Comment: It works as expected on my machine and also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9vgebtrk/). Did you link your sheet correctly?

Comment: Yes,ihave Linked correctly and all other properties are working properly,but the cursor:pointer property isn't working

Comment: What browser are you using? Any other important info? Other classnames etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That property only works on hover like this:

```css
button:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Write this in CSS:

```css
button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: This answer has already been provided

Answer (score -1):

if you want on hover then try `button:hover{cursor: pointer}`